# How to select a repeatable random number with setseed in postgres sql?

Tags: sql, postgresql, random, random-seed

What I am trying to achieve is selecting a control group for a process.  To do this I am using random(), and for debugging / consistency I would like to be able to set the random number in a repeatable fashion.  Meaning, I run the query once it assigns user 123 random number .001.  At a different time I delete the previous data, I call the same query, and once again user 123 is assigned random number .001.

I have tried:

```
SELECT setseed(0);
SELECT 1, random() from generate_series(1,10);
```

I receive a different random number with every run.

```
SELECT 1, setseed(0), random() from generate_series(1,10);
```

Each row receives the same random number, which is useless.

I'm sure there is something I don't understand here.  Any help is appreciated.

Comment: With the first one, did you run that as two separate statements from your application? Or did you send it as a single string containing both statements?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Do a `union all` of the `setseed()` query with the desired query. It is necessary to match the column types from both queries. `setseed()` returns `void`.

```
select setseed(0), null

union all

select null, random()
from generate_series(1, 10)

offset 1
;
```

The `offset 1` clause eliminates the `setseed() row` from the result set

Comment: Hey, This suggestion achieves the goal.  A repeatable random number! Thanks.  However I did have to replace "''::void" with "null" as the former throws a 'void not an integer error' in postgresql.  I'll leave it open a bit to see if someone else jumps in with another way, but thanks for the help.

Comment: @user3055034 Yes, the `''::void` was wrong but it did not throw an error here in 9.3.5. What is your version?

Comment: It would be helpful to know why this is effective and two standalone statements are not. I don't see the chain of logic that bought you to this conclusion.

Comment: @Craig As an example, one possible problem the OP might be having is that prepared statements in PHP do not allow for multiple statements: http://php.net/manual/en/function.pg-prepare.php

Comment: @ClodoaldoNeto Ah, so you think they're running two statements in a single application API call. Good guess, though nice to explain.

Comment: The version I am running is actually greenplum.  Thanks for your help on this Clodoaldo.